# 1004, Application-defined or Object-defined error when setting a Range as a variable with `.End(xlDown)` function

Tags: vba, loops, range

I've wrote a code to delete rows which cell in column five has a value of 0:

```
Sub deletedata()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3.Calidad CREDITICIA")
Dim r As Range
Set r = ws3.Range("E20", Range("E20").End(xlDown))
n = r.Cells.Count

With ws3
         For i = n + 20 To 20
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 5)) And .Cells(i, 5) = 0 Then
                .Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
            End If
            Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

When it arrives to the instruction in which I set r range: `Set r = ws3.Range("E20", Range("E20").End(xlDown))` I get the 1004 error:

> 1004, Application-defined or Object-defined

I've tried so many things, between them I tried a MyCell loop, but I get still the error when setting range
¿Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the worksheets protected? Or might the VBA code be on the sheet as opposed to be in a module?

Comment: The code is in Thisworkbook instead of a module, Would you explain me why that fact could make this code not to work?

Comment: I can't give you a detailed explanation. But I have experienced this in my VBA Projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely has to do with the implicit reference to `ActiveSheet`:

```
                        ' Right here
Set r = ws3.Range("E20", Range("E20").End(xlDown))
```

Try this instead:

```
Set r = ws3.Range("E20", ws3.Range("E20").End(xlDown))
```